# Из ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> достать только значения

Tags: java, arraylist, android-spinner, java-hashmap

Это вообще возможно? 
Мне нужно вывести в спиннер значения, а ключи нужны только для получения по ним других данных в зависимости от выбранного значения в спиннере.

```
/**
 * Asynctask для получения json по HTTP-запросу (список сайтов)
 */
private class getSites extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        // запрос по url и получение ответа
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(urlSites);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONArray sites = new JSONArray(jsonStr);


                // проходимся по всем пунктам
                for (int i = 0; i < sites.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = sites.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = String.valueOf(c.getInt("id"));
                    String name = c.getString("name");

                    // hash map для каждого пункта спиннера
                    HashMap<String, String> siteItem = new HashMap<>();

                    // добавление каждого элемента в HashMap key => value
                    siteItem.put("id", id);
                    siteItem.put("name", name);
                    sitesForSpinner.add(name);
                            Log.e(TAG, sitesForSpinner.toString());
                    // добавление в лист
                    siteList.add(siteItem);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error (spinner): " + e.getMessage());
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "Json parsing error (spinner): " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        //обновляем данные в спиннере
        spinner.setItems(sitesForSpinner);
    }
}
```

Comment: В каком виде вы хотите получить значения? У вас список из ассоциативных массивов, в каждом из которых может быть разное количество значений. Вы хотите все значения записать в новый ArrayList?

Comment: @Кирилл Малышев  на самом деле у меня есть json следующего содержания: [{"id":1,"name":"somewhere1.com"},{"id":2,"name":"somewhere2.com"},{"id":3,"name":"life.org"},{"id":5,"name":"life.ru"},{"id":6,"name":"rbc.ru"}]. В результате парсинга я всё запихнул в ArrayList. Это было неверно?

Comment: Да, в ArrayList так нормально. Вы хотите получить какие значения в итоге?

Comment: Да, я распарсил json. Имею список сайтов и id. Сайты надо вывести в спиннер, и определить id выбранного сайта в спиннере. Для спиннера использовал библиотеку https://github.com/jaredrummler/Material-Spinner?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=3124 и там как я понял можно данные подсунуть только так: spinner.setItems(List <>);

Comment: Приложите код, как вы парсите json. Я думаю, вам нужно создавать HashMap<String, Integer> с ключами - сайтами и значениями - id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен один HashMap. Ключи у него будут - имена сайтов, а значения - id.

Создайте HashMap вместо ArrayList:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> sites = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

При парсинге json записывайте туда значения:

```
int id = c.getInt("id");
String name = c.getString("name");
sites.put(name, id);
```

Чтобы вывести в Spinner, вам нужно получить все ключи. Воспользуйтесь методом `keySet()`. Он возвращает `Set`. Если вам нужен список, передайте этот `Set` ему в конструктор:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(sites.keySet());
spinner.setItems(names);
```

Послу выбора элемента в спиннере, чтобы получить id сайта, зная его имя, используйте метод `get()`:

```
int id = sites.get(name);
```